# Great Plains Find Sales Orders

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-gp

I have created sales orders in Great Plains, however, I cannot find them in the right place in the system. Although my code executes without any errors, I do not find this transaction under Sales > All Sales Transactions. Instead, I see them under Sales > Sales Documents.

Is it in a pending state?

[image]
[image]

```cs
        public void CreateOrder()
    {
        CompanyKey companyKey;
        Context context;
        SalesOrder salesOrder;
        SalesDocumentTypeKey salesOrderType;
        CustomerKey customerKey;
        BatchKey batchKey;
        SalesOrderLine salesOrderLine;
        ItemKey orderedItem;
        Quantity orderedAmount;
        Policy salesOrderCreatePolicy;

        // Create a context with which to call the service
        context = new Context();

        // Specify which company to use (sample company)
        companyKey = new CompanyKey();
        companyKey.Id = (-1);

        // Set up the context object
        context.OrganizationKey = (OrganizationKey)companyKey;

        // Create a sales order object
        salesOrder = new SalesOrder();

        // Create a sales document type key for the sales order
        salesOrderType = new SalesDocumentTypeKey();
        salesOrderType.Type = SalesDocumentType.Order;

        // Populate the document type key of the sales order object
        salesOrder.DocumentTypeKey = salesOrderType;

        // Create a customer key
        customerKey = new CustomerKey();
        customerKey.Id = "JONESJ008";

        // Set the customer key property of the sales order object
        salesOrder.CustomerKey = customerKey;
        // Create a batch key
        batchKey = new BatchKey();
        batchKey.Id = "SALES ORDERS";

        // Set the batch key property of the sales order object
        salesOrder.BatchKey = batchKey;

        // Create a sales order line to specify the ordered item
        salesOrderLine = new SalesOrderLine();

        // Create an item key
        orderedItem = new ItemKey();
        orderedItem.Id = "32X IDE";

        // Set the item key property of the sales order line object
        salesOrderLine.ItemKey = orderedItem;

        // Create a sales order quantity object
        orderedAmount = new Quantity();
        orderedAmount.Value = 4;

        // Set the quantity of the sales order line object
        salesOrderLine.Quantity = orderedAmount;

        // Create an array of sales order lines
        // Initialize the array with sales order line object
        SalesOrderLine[] orders = { salesOrderLine };

        // Add the sales order line array to the sales order
        salesOrder.Lines = orders;

        // Get the create policy for the sales order object
        salesOrderCreatePolicy = wsDynamicsGP.GetPolicyByOperation("CreateSalesOrder", context);

        // Create the sales order
        wsDynamicsGP.CreateSalesOrder(salesOrder, context, salesOrderCreatePolicy);


    }
```

I have looked in Sales > All Sales Transactions. I can use the API to pull this order out. I am using the sample company file, Fabrikam, Inc. Here's how I set up my context:

```cs
        public GPOrders()
    {
        wsDynamicsGP = new DynamicsGP();
        // Be sure the default credentials are used
        wsDynamicsGP.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        // Create a context with which to call the web service
        context = new Context();

        // Specify which company to use (sample company)
        companyKey = new CompanyKey();
        companyKey.Id = (-1);

        // Set up the context object
        context.OrganizationKey = (OrganizationKey)companyKey;
        context.CultureName = "en-US";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found them under Sales > Sales Documents. The transactions never posted, so they weren't under Sales > All Sales Transactions.